# Armature appears in edit mode but not pose/object mode

Tags: animation, armature

The armature I made for my model doesn't seem to appear in pose mode nor object mode. I'm not sure if this is the result of creating an animation (the armature seems to have disappeared after I created a base animation and added edited versions of it by creating actions in the action editor).

The armature appears just fine in edit mode, so I'm not sure what exactly is going on.

Does this have anything to do with deleting key frames?

**Edit:**
Thanks for all the suggestions! I still can't find a solution so I've uploaded the file. If anyone can help that'll be great.

[image]

Comment: Have you verified that the object is on the correct layer and that the layer is visible?

Comment: I'm quite sure that nothing is about keyframing; maybe you should upload your .blend file to examinate

Comment: Is your armature displayed in X-Ray mode to be visible beneath the mesh?

Comment: your armature is hidden, select your armature, go to pose mode and hit Alt+H to show them again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pose bones are hidden.

[image]

To selectively unhide the bones click the plus sign next to "Pose" and select the closed eyes.

To unhide all posed bones at once, select "Pose", hover over your mesh and press <kbd>alt</kbd> +  <kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: oh my ...god...i thought i unhid it but i guess i was doing it completely wrong. thanks for answering such a simple and noob question!!!

Comment: @hana Not a noob question, I'm sure you just forgot! Here's a noob question ;-) http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53477/edit-a-mesh-in-pose-position/53480#53480

Comment: @hana Don't forget to "accept" the answer, if this solved your problem (instead of putting [SOLVED] in the subject line ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Put your armature in X-Ray Mode.

Comment: i did try that out but didn't seem to work. and i did check if it's in the correct layer as well, and that didn't seem to be the issue. 
however i MIGHT be doing something wrong considering i'm still very new to blender. i might upload my file if i can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things that seemed to not work... so I open New > General > Deleted Cube > Append > Selected the 3D Sculpture I need to Bone (lol) and boom! when I add Bone, it shows. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Had my bone show in edit mode but not Pose mode, my solution[image: 3 steps image]

1. No Bones visible.
2. Viewport Overlays tick box for bones not ticked.
3. Ticked the Bones box. Bones now visible.

ps.took me few hours to find this solution, thought i would post.