# Edit a rigged mesh in pose position?

Tags: mesh, armature, edit-mode, pose-mode

I'd like to edit my mesh in the pose position so that the wire frame is in the pose position as well.

I have "view in edit mode" enabled for the armature modifier, but it only shows the mesh in reset position.

[image: wire frame and pose position mesh]

Comment: Can you add more details/a .blend file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6836/how-to-edit-a-rotated-mesh-in-pose-mode

Comment: @Mentalist The question is similar, but the accepted answer doesn't answer my question, it is only the last line of my question.

Comment: Ah, I see where you were stuck now. Glad Paul's answer helped you get it sorted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In *Armature Modifier* panel enable both ***Display modifier in Edit Mode*** and ***Adjust edit cage to modifier result*** buttons.
[image]